# How to increment the obj key?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, logic

I was trying to find a same number in a string, but the obj key wasnt want to increment the value, and its still readed as a negation

```js
function yOrN(phone) {
  const temp = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < phone.length; i++) {
    const el = String(phone[i]);
    if (el.length > 10) {
      temp.push("No");
      break;
    }
    let tempObj = {};
    for (let j = 0; j < el.length; j++) {
      const em = el[j];
      if (!tempObj[el[j]]) {
        tempObj[el[j]] = 0;           //! this side make me stucked rn
      } else if (tempObj) {
        tempObj[el[j]] = tempObj[el[j]] + 1;
      }
    }
    for (const num in tempObj) {
      if (tempObj[num] < 3 || tempObj[num] > 4) {
        temp.push("No");
        break;
      } else {
        temp.push("Yes");
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return temp;
}
console.log(yOrN([98887432, 12345890]));
```

the expected output was ["yes", "no"] :(
and its still ["no", "no"]

```
{ '2': 1, '3': 1, '4': 1, '7': 1, '8': 5, '9': 1 } for the index 0
{ '0': 1, '1': 1, '2': 1, '3': 1, '4': 1, '5': 1, '8': 1, '9': 1 } for the index 1
```

Comment: Please explain what your desired result is, it is not clear. Also what does the `el` array contain?

Comment: what is the original string/obj to read? Last line is what you are wanting?

Comment: im so sorry guys, i already update my code

Comment: for index 0 : `{ '2': 1,...` `1 < 3` is `true` -->  `temp.push("No");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in any case your function cann't return a `Yes` with your actual arguments values.

I think you are looking for [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) ?

```js
console.log( yOrN( [98887432, 12345890]) );

function yOrN(phone) 
  {
  const temp = [];
  
  for (let el of phone.map(String))
    {
    let res = 'Yes';
    if (el.length > 10)
      res = 'No';
    else
      {
      let tempObj = [...el].reduce((a,c)=> ( a[c] ??= 0, a[c]++, a), {})
      if ( Object.values(tempObj).some( v => v < 3 || v > 4)) 
        res = 'No';

      console.log( res, JSON.stringify( tempObj ))  
      }
    temp.push(res);
    }
  return temp;
  }
```